# How do you configure mocks before Autowired?

Tags: spring, testing, mocking

I want to set up mock data using Mockito before my test.  However, the autowire happens before the `@Before` so my tests that expect data to be present is missing.  Is there a way around it?

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {
       Foo.class
    }
)
public class FooTest {
    @MockBean
    final Programs programs;
    @Autowired
    final Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setPrograms() {

        when(programs.findAll())
            .thenReturn(
                List.of(
                    "A", "B", "C"
                )
            );

    }

    @Test
    public void foo() {
      assertThat(foo.getBlah()).isNotEmpty();
    }
}

interface Programs {
  List<String> findAll();
}

class Foo {

  // I have more complicated structures than a list, for example only.
  private List<String> blah;
  @Autowired
  private Programs programs;

  public List<String> getBlah() { return blah; }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    blah = programs.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are doing and trying to achieve? Because Mockito provides methods like `when` or `given` to specify what methods (or getter of properties) should return in your tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Programs` is an interface; in reality it's extends `CrudRepository` I am able to instantiate a copy of it even a mock with a `@Configuration/@Bean`.  This solution ensures that everything (except the mocks) are managed by Spring including the `PostConstruct` lifecycle.

This approach allows me to have Spring components that contain `PostConstruct`s that use JPA without having to set up an initial database with the proper data.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {
        Foo.class,
        StackOverflowTest.ProgramsConfiguration.class
    }
)
public class StackOverflowTest {
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Configuration
    static class ProgramsConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Programs programs() {

            final Programs mock = mock(Programs.class);
            when(mock.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
            return mock;

        }

    }

    @Test
    public void foo() {

        assertThat(foo.getBlah())
            .isNotEmpty()
            .containsExactly("A", "B", "C");

    }
}

interface Programs {
    List<String> findAll();
}

class Foo {

    private List<String> blah;

    @Autowired
    private Programs programs;

    public List<String> getBlah() {

        return blah;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        blah = programs.findAll();
    }
}
```

I actually found that I had solved this problem a while back when I was trying to get JOOQ working with `PostConstruct`s as well using a `MockDslContextConfiguration`.  Took me a bit of time to realize it was the same situation.

```java
@Configuration
public class MockDslContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DSLContext dslContext() {

        return DSL.using(new MockConnection(mockExecuteContext -> new MockResult[]{
            new MockResult(0, Mockito.mock(Result.class)),
            new MockResult(0, Mockito.mock(Result.class))
        }), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    }
}
```

Though this Q&A is more general and not limited to JOOQ.

This has a limitation of that I can only have one set of data for the test per test class.

Answer (score 0):

Following your example I have developed the next ones:

```
public interface Programs {
  List<String> findAll();
}


public class Foo {

  // I have more complicated structures than a list, for example only.
  private List<String> blah;

  @Autowired
  private Programs programs;

  public List<String> getBlah() { return blah; }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    blah = programs.findAll();
  }
}
```

Above ones equals to your provided code. Now, "the changes":

```
// Only for testing purpose, you can use any of your own ones
public class ProgramsImpl implements Programs {

  @Override
  public List<String> findAll() {
    return asList("1", "2", "3");
  }
}
```

And the junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {
            Foo.class, ProgramsImpl.class
    }
)
public class FooTest {

  @SpyBean
  Programs programs;

  @Autowired
  Foo foo;

  @Before
  public void prepare() {
    when(programs.findAll())
            .thenReturn(
                    List.of(
                            "A", "B", "C"
                    )
            );
    this.foo.init();
  }

  @Test
  public void foo() {
    assertEquals(asList("A", "B", "C"), foo.getBlah());
  }
}
```

The above test works as expected, that is, although `ProgramsImpl.findAll` returns `"1", "2", "3"` the `when` clause included will overwrite it with your own one.

However, as you probably will figure out really the **`@PostConstruct` is invoked twice**: one due to `@Autowire` and the second one due to `init`.

**If you want to avoid it**, you need to remove `@Autowire` in your test and create your custom instance of `foo` inside `@Before` (using a "normal constructor"). For example:

```
public class Foo {
  ...
  private Programs programs;

  @Autowired
  public Foo(Programs programs) {
    this.programs = programs;
  }
  ...
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {
            ProgramsImpl.class
    }
)
public class FooTest {

  @SpyBean
  Programs programs;

  Foo foo;

  @Before
  public void prepare() {
    when(programs.findAll())
            .thenReturn(
                    List.of(
                            "A", "B", "C"
                    )
            );
    this.foo = new Foo(programs);
    this.foo.init();
  }

  @Test
  public void foo() {
    assertEquals(asList("A", "B", "C"), foo.getBlah());
  }

 }
```

Comment: As you had noted there's the double init issue, also the Foo that is created in the @Before is not managed by spring which means the injections it comes with no longer work.

What I would need to do is create a separate configuration class that provides the object, I'm trying to extract my sample for it right now.

Comment: Of course, when I do that, I can only have one set of data for the test per test class.

Comment: `Of course, when I do that, I can only have one set of data for the test per test class` I include only one example, you can generate what you need for your tests. Included the required custom initialization before every one (with different `when` clauses) instead of in a "global way" for all of them

Comment: `also the Foo that is created in the @Before is not managed by spring` => that is not a requisite in Junit tests, I mean, usually you create the main class in the way you want and mock the related ones (because every one will have its own tests). So, it is suitable create instance of `Foo` in Junit using a constructor because it does not change what you really want to test.